# Dynamic call of google analytics methods

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I am trying to figure out a way to create a dynamic call for the analytics client

```
data =  analytics.data().ga().get(tableID, // Table Id.
                            startDate, // Start date.
                            endDate, // End date.
                            metrics).setDimensions(dimensions).setSort(sort).setFilters(filters)
                            .setSegment(segment).setSamplingLevel("DEFAULT").setStartIndex(1).setMaxResults(1000).setOutput("json")
                            .setFields(fields).execute();
```

The parameters are taken from a web service call. How to make this thing dynamic? Lets say that I want to ommit some properties. Does any one have a clue?I want it to be

```
data =  analytics.data().ga().get(tableID, // Table Id.
                            startDate, // Start date.
                            endDate, // End date.
                            metrics).setDimensions(dimensions).setSamplingLevel("DEFAULT").setStartIndex(1).setMaxResults(1000).setOutput("json")
                            .setFields(fields).execute();
```

How can this be done during code execution?